# catch exceptions that caused by connection error in ftplib

Tags: python, exception, ftplib

I'm trying to upload lots of files using python's `ftplib`.
What kind of exception should I catch to be sure the problem is a connection error (so I can re-connect)?

---

Edit:
I tried `all_errors` in this scenario:

- Connected to FTP server by `ftplib` and paused application (via debugger) before file upload
- Closed connection via server
- Resumed Application

With this code:

```
        try:        
            self.f.cwd(dest)
            return self.f.storbinary(('STOR '+n).encode('utf-8'), open(f,'rb'))
        except ftplib.all_errors as e:
            print e
```

exception caught but `all_errors` was empty:

```
e   EOFError:   
    args    tuple: ()   
    message str:
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you wanna tell us. So `ftplib.all_errors` worked but it was empty?

Comment: @dav1d: yes;(check my second edit); not always but most of times it has a empty tuple! (while it is caught!!)

Comment: `e` is the instance of the error which is caught, it simply means no arguments were passed on initilization to the EOFError. That is nothing you have to care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look it up in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.error_reply

Also don't forget: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.all_errors

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
import socket
import ftplib

try:
    s = ftplib.FTP(server , user , password) 
except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    print "%s" % e
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to catch exceptions both to and from a ftp server may be:

```
import ftplib, os

def from_ftp( server, path, data, filename = None ):
    '''Store the ftp data content to filename (anonymous only)'''
    if not filename:
        filename = os.path.basename( os.path.realpath(data) )

    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP( server )
        print( server + ' -> '+ ftp.login() )        
        print( server + ' -> '+ ftp.cwd(path) ) 
        with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
            print( server + ' -> '+ ftp.retrbinary( 'RETR ' + data, out.write ) ) 

    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print( 'Ftp fail -> ', e )
        return False

    return True

def to_ftp( server, path, file_input, file_output = None ):
    '''Store a file to ftp (anonymous only)'''
    if not file_output:
        file_output = os.path.basename( os.path.realpath(file_input) )

    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP( server )
        print( server + ' -> '+ ftp.login() )        
        print( server + ' -> '+ ftp.cwd(path) ) 
        with open( file_input, 'rb' ) as out:
            print( server + ' -> '+ ftp.storbinary( 'STOR ' + file_output, out ) ) 

    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print( 'Ftp fail -> ', e )
        return False

    return True
```